# Find $f(x)$ concave and $g(y)$ convex such that $h(x,y)=(f(x)/g(y))^2$ is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm looking for two functions $f(x)$ concave and $g(y)$ convex such that the square of their ratio $h(x,y)=(f(x)/g(y))^2$ is convex. The function $f$ must map a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$. The function $g$ must map a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to at least the interval $[0,1]$ (could be bigger). Both functions must be strictly increasing.

I am starting to believe that there exist no such functions.

Comment: A constant function? Or do you require strict convexity?

Comment: Oops, I meant to say _strictly increasing_. I've corrected the question. Weak convexity works.

Comment: If you get rid of the strict monotonicity of $f$ and $g$ then $f=-|x|$ and $g=|x|$ work. In particular, $f=-g$ works, but violates monotonicity.

Comment: Yes and note that $g$ is a function of $y$ not $x$.

Comment: "I am starting to believe there exist no such functions." In my view, you should have been surprised from the start if there _were_ any. Convexity is a _fragile_ property. It is the exception, not the rule, and very easily broken by simple manipulation.